# How to create calculated column to show 2 fields where If field1 is not blank and Field 2 drop down selected specific value

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath-2013

I'm not an expert in Sharepoint, and need to create a Infopath form as displayed here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X02oz.png

Problem: How to create a field which provide the total value

Note: Assigned Learners Licenses - Total # where Name is PRESENT and License Type is Learners
Purchased Learners Licenses - Total# all records in the list
Remaining Learners Licenses - Total# records where Name is BLANK and License Type is Learners

Appreciate your help